# Why amp page isn't showing up in google search result?

Tags: amp-html, structured-data

MY website https://aptadvantage.herokuapp.com is amp-validated and heres the validation test link https://search.google.com/test/amp?id=RXDZyZFaZSKROBLVZPJTKQ

I only have a single amp page on this site.I dont have a non-amp version of this site. Now the problem is why google cant find any amp pages on my site even after successfull amp validation? when I am searching the site from mobile the amp icon is not showing up in the google search result.. but I think my site has been cached in amp cache, and this is the amp-cache link https://aptadvantage-herokuapp-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/aptadvantage.herokuapp.com

And there's another problem in Structured data testing but I cant figure out how to solve this?

Comment: Did you get your AMP page indexed in your Google search console?

Comment: its on "Indexing Requested" state

Comment: Than I guess wait till it gets indexed properly in AMP section of Google search console. After that you will be able to see that page with AMP icon on Google search page.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not going to prevent your site from being indexed, your lack of Structured Data may affect your ranking, especially as Google uses it to decide how AMP content is [placed in search results](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/enhance-amp).  This is why the AMP validator is providing the warning.

Structured Data should describe the type of content being displayed on the page. There's a couple of ways to implement it, but Google suggests using LD+JSON in the page head, for instance the following example explains that the site is part of an organization, and provides ways to get in contact with it.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "url": "http://www.example.com",
  "name": "Unlimited Ball Bearings Corp.",
  "contactPoint": {
    "@type": "ContactPoint",
    "telephone": "+1-401-555-1212",
    "contactType": "Customer service"
  }
}
</script>
```

You can learn more about getting started with structured data and AMP [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/enhance-amp) and [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data).

Google [also has a nifty structured data validator tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/) that you can run on your page to make sure there's no errors.

Comment: Then you need to just wait for Google to index the page, which can take anywhere from a couple hours to a couple of weeks.

Comment: Sir can you please check my amp-html and tell me if theres any problem with my coding?

Comment: As long you're not blocking the search crawler with `robots.txt` and it passes the Google AMP validator then you're good to go.